# AngularJS ng-bind once default value

Tags: angularjs

I have a "view" page constructed with AngularJS where I display the value of a model as follows:

```
<span ng-bind="doctor.address || '[Not defined yet]'"></span>
```

If the value of `doctor.address` is undefined I correctly get the `[Not defined yet]` text.

Since this is a "view" page, I know the values won't change while it is displayed, so, I wanted to save some watchers and use the ng-bind once feature:

```
<span ng-bind="::doctor.address || '[Not defined yet]'"></span>
```

but if there is a valid an existing value for `doctor.address` I still get the `[Not defined yet]` text.

If I use the following:

```
<span ng-bind="::doctor.address"></span>
```

I correctly get the doctor address value.

This doesn't work either:

```
<span ng-bind="::doctor.address">[Not defined yet]</span>
```

So, how can I define a "default value" when using the ng-bind once feature?

**EDIT:** this is the actual code with a last test that didn't work:

```
...
Restangular.one('doctors', params.doctorId).get().then(function(response) {
  $scope.doctor = response;
  $scope.test = "Hello!!!";
}, function(errorResponse) {
  console.log(errorResponse);
});
...
```

and this is the markup:

```
<span ng-bind="::test || '[Not defined yet]'"></span>
```

and still no idea of what might be wrong (the async call would be affecting?)

This is a plunk (forked from the one on Alex Pollan answer) where I can reproduce the issue (I used a custom promise): https://plnkr.co/edit/pjPeTZq8GxaDfvEWk3xV?p=preview

Comment: Which version of angularjs are you using? Seems to work for 1.4.5 http://jsfiddle.net/3t4yyh7p/12/

Comment: @Nils, I'm using angularjs 1.4.4

Comment: Seems to work with 1.4.4 as well http://jsfiddle.net/injulkarnilesh/3t4yyh7p/13/

Comment: @Nils, yes, you're right. A simple example like your fiddle works fine in my code. My `$scope.doctor` gets populated via `Restangular` and it contains the address. Odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<span ng-bind="::(doctor.address || '[Not defined yet]')"></span>
```

Hope it helps

UPDATE: It is funny because...

```
<span ng-bind="::doctor.address || '[Not defined yet]'"></span>
```

... works for me too (AngularJs v1.4.x)

Check: https://plnkr.co/edit/9jeau6x3pKdlggZ0DzO1?p=preview

Comment: I will upgrade to angularjs 1.4.5 and test again.

Comment: I upgraded to 1.4.8 and I'm having the same problem. Testing with something like your plunk into my code worked great. So there might be something strange when `$scope.doctor` gets populated via `Restangular` because the address is there.

Comment: Do you have the value doctor.address defined somehow before Restangular set it? One time binding stop watching once the value becomes defined (!undefined).

Comment: silly question... Is response.address defined when you debug your code?

Comment: before the `Restangular` call I initialize the scope variable as `$scope.doctor = {};`. Also, if I `console.log(response.address)` I get the address of the doctor correctly. It is very odd.

Comment: Alex, I just tested the code removing the initialize code `$scope.doctor = {};` in order to avoid the variable from being "alive" before the `Restangular` call but the issue persists. Not using the "ng-bind once" but the regular "ng-bind" works fine. I'm still struggling to save those unnecessary watchers :)

Comment: Just as a test... Could you try to replace Restangular call with a mock using a promise or with $http.get instead?

Comment: Just tested making the call using $http.get and also with a custom promise that resolves itself with a hardcoded object after 2 seconds (without making an async call) and the same issue persists.

Comment: Here is the plunk (forked from the one of this answer) where I can reproduce the issue: https://plnkr.co/edit/pjPeTZq8GxaDfvEWk3xV?p=preview

Comment: According to documentation: "One-time expressions will stop recalculating once they are stable, which happens after the first digest if the expression result is a non-undefined value."... and the literal '[Not defined yet]' makes the expression DEFINED. That's why it doesn't work as expected. If you remove that literal string it works fine (https://plnkr.co/edit/6rllFpIUuDIwWJoStxwj?p=preview).... I think to make it work with one time binding is not worth the effort and the result won't be better. My suggestion is to use the regular binding.